# Loading Windows OS using Mainline U-Boot bootloader

Tags: bootloader, windows

How could I load Windows OS with a bootloader that is **Mainline U-Boot**?

Is this possible? Do we have any documentation that will guide us on this approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, should be supported since 2016:

https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2016-May/254340.html

You'll need to load Seabios:

https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2016-May/254326.html

> Do we have any documentation

Readme.x86; windows is a normal payload with bios emulation and ACPI support.